# Keen IO - How to find the difference between two Keen.Series

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, keen-io

How do you find the difference between two series (Keen.Series) and then plot it on a line chart?

I figured out how to find the difference between two metrics (Keen.Metric), but can't figure out how to grab each result from both series and subtract them accordingly.

If this helps, here is how to find the difference between two metrics:

```
Keen.onChartsReady(function(){
  // Create a Metric containing our total $ amount in Keen IO credit card transactions (to and from)
  // Excludes: refund transactions from Stripe to card and declined cards
  var myMetric = new Keen.Metric("Stripe_Event",
    analysisType: "sum",
    targetProperty: "data.object.amount",
    filters: [
      {"property_name":"data.object.captured","operator":"eq","property_value":true},
      {"property_name":"data.object.amount_refunded","operator":"eq","property_value":0}]
  });

  // Create a Metric containing our total number of refunds
  var myMetric2 = new Keen.Metric("Stripe_Event", {
    analysisType: "sum",
    targetProperty: "data.object.amount_refunded",
    filters: [
    {"property_name":"type","operator":"eq","property_value":"charge.refunded"}]
  });

  // Find the difference and convert to dollars
  myMetric.getResponse(function(response){
    firstValue = response.result;
    myMetric2.getResponse(function(nextResponse){
      secondValue = nextResponse.result;
      difference = firstValue-secondValue;
      dollar = difference / 100;
      console.log(dollar);

      //Create a Number visualization for that metric.
      var myNumberVisualization = new Keen.Number(myMetric2, {
        height: "300",
        width: "600",
        prefix:"$",
        label: "Revenue"
      });

    //Draw the visualization in a div
    myNumberVisualization.draw(document.getElementById("myDiv"),
      {"result":dollar});
    });
  });
});
```

I figured out how take one Keen.Series and convert each result into dollar format (Stripe API outputs transactions in pennies and must be divided by 100 to find the dollar value):

```
Keen.onChartsReady(function() {
  // Create a Series
  var mySeries = new Keen.Series("Stripe_Event", {
    analysisType: "sum",
    timeframe: "this_month",
    interval: "daily",
    targetProperty: "data.object.amount",
  });

  // Convert results from pennies to dollars
  var resultsInDollars = {}

  mySeries.getResponse(function(response){
    result = response.result
    $.each(result, function(index, object){
      result[index]["value"] = object["value"]/100
    });

    resultsInDollars = {
      result: result
      }

    // Line chart settings
    var myLineChart = new Keen.LineChart(mySeries, {
          height: 240,
          width: 300,
          xAxisLabelAngle:45
    });
    // Draw line chart
    myLineChart.draw(document.getElementById("overview"),resultsInDollars);
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a gist for something very similar -- dividing two line charts.

https://gist.github.com/wetzler/9127225

Just change the operation from division to subtraction and you should be good to go.

Comment: Here's a gist sharing a solution derived from Josh's answer. https://gist.github.com/brentchow/9147264